# add associative array into another

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, array-push

i want to add one associative array into another but when i use array_push it overrides the value of previous one

```
<?php
$tem = ["blue","ss"];
$len = count($tem);
print_r($len);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $data = [
        'code' => $tem[$i],
        'discount_type' => 'percent',   
    ];
    $a=array();
    $result[$i] =array_push($a,$data);
    print_r($a);
}
?>
```

and the output is

```
2Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => blue [discount_type] => percent ) ) 
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => ss [discount_type] => percent ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The one problem is that you reset the `$a` array inside the loop, so it will only ever contain the last item.  Also, you don't assign the return from `array_push()` as it updates the array itself (but you never use `$result[$i]` anyway)...

So your code would end up something like..

```
$tem = ["blue","ss"];
$len = count($tem);
print_r($len);
$a=array();
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $data = [
            'code' => $tem[$i],
            'discount_type' => 'percent',
    ];
    array_push($a,$data);
}
print_r($a);
```

You can also shorten the code using a `foreach` loop and creating the array as you add it to the result...

```
$tem = ["blue","ss"];
$a=array();
foreach ( $tem as $t )  {
    $a[] = [
        'code' =>  $t,
        'discount_type' => 'percent',
    ];
}
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Is there any progress with this?